# How to tell ssh not to ask for a password

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a script which loops through hosts and executes commands like so

```
while read host; do
  ssh "user@$host" 'echo "$(pwd)"'
done
```

the problem is some hosts ask for a password, is there a way to exit with 0 if there is a host that asks for a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 host.example.com
```

But it will exit non-zero... (specifically 255 with `OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`)